# Adding Multiple Adapter Into Fragment

Tags: dagger

Hello all can you advice me how to add multiple different adapter in one fragment using dagger ?

````
@Module
class HomeFragmentModule  {

    @Provides
    internal fun provideHomeInteractor(interactor: HomeInteractor): HomeMVPInteractor = interactor

    @Provides
    internal fun provideRegisterPresenter(presenter: HomePresenter<HomeView, HomeMVPInteractor>) : HomeMVPPresenter<HomeView, HomeMVPInteractor> = presenter


    @Provides
    @Named("ppobAdapter")
    fun providePpobAdapter(): PpobAdapter = PpobAdapter(ArrayList())


    @Provides
    @Named("sliderAdapter")
    internal fun provideSliderAdapter(): SliderAdapter = SliderAdapter(ArrayList())


} ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    @Inject
    @Named("ppobAdapter")
    lateinit var ppobAdapter: PpobAdapter

    @Inject
    @Name("sliderAdapter")
    lateinit var sliderAdapter: SliderAdapter

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        DaggerAppComponent
            .builder()
            .build()
            .inject(this)
    }
}
```

With a component that looks like this:

```
@Component(modules = [HomeFragmentModule::class])
interface AppComponent {

    fun inject(fragment: HomeFragment)
}
```

For a really good intro to dagger I always advise [this tutorial series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLRSX8UrKuHlzGlyBPD2OQDInhZsNmX_nZ)

Comment: i had set interface App Component like this 

`@Singleton
@Component(modules = [(AndroidInjectionModule::class), (AppModule::class), (ActivityBuilder::class)])
interface AppComponent {


    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }

    fun inject(app: MyApp)

}`

Comment: That's not a pattern for dagger that I'm familiar with, without seeing the rest of your code I can't comment on it.

Comment: basicly im followed https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/android-kotlin-mvp-architecture but the soyce is using one adapter for 1 fragment so i try to modified that for my app